# run python telegram bot after reboot and if it's crashes on AWS EC2

Tags: python-3.x, linux, amazon-ec2, cron, telegram-bot

I created a telegram bot using `pyrogram` and it crashes after few hours. Sometimes I stop the EC2 myself to reduce the cost. I created these cron jobs inside /`etc/crontab` but it seems they are not working as expected.

1. Cronjob 1 is to run the python file after EC2 reboot.
2. Cronjob 2 is to restart the bot if it got crashed.

Here is my crontab content.

```
@reboot sudo pgrep -f bot.py || sudo nohup /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/bot.py & > /home/ubuntu/startOnReboot.log

*/2 * * * * sudo pgrep -f bot.py || sudo nohup /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/bot.py & > /home/ubuntu/restartBotAfterCrash.log
```

I would like to know whether my cronjob is not correct or any solution better than this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `sudo` in the cronjob,  use `sudo crontab -e` instead to have it run as root.

Futhermore, `& >` is different from `&>` - did you mean to redirect all output to the specified file or run the cronjob in the background and redirect stdout? If it's the latter, you don't need to tell cron to run it as a background job and the redirection should come *before* the ampersand (which you should drop anyway).

Last, you probably want to use a systemd service for this instead.

Comment: do you have an idea which user linux uses to run crontab ?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. In general, use a user with the minimum amount of permissions needed to run the app.